# CRF equivalent in deep learning

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language, sequence-analysis, conditional-random-field

Conditional Random Fields (CRFs) is a typical solution for a sequence labelling/segmentation problem. For example, a sequence is a string and CRFs are used to label each word as being a part of a company name, a location, an event, etc.

What is currently the state-of-the-art equivalent in the deep learning community to CRFs for sequence labelling/segmentation?

CRFs have several implementations, including C++ and Java. Does an implementation exist on the deep learning side?

Answer (score 2):

https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.03475 (*De-identification of Patient Notes with Recurrent Neural Networks*) uses a neural network with a "label sequence optimization layer" as the top layer to do some sequence tagging, which could be seen as a "deep learning" equivalent to CRF.

See *Section 2.2.4 Label sequence optimization layer*:

> The label sequence optimization layer takes the sequence of
>   probability vectors $\mathbf{a}_{1:n}$ from the label prediction layer
>   as input, and outputs a sequence of labels $y_{1:n}$, where $y_{i}$ is
>   the label assigned to the token $x_{i}$.
>
> The simplest strategy to select the label $y_{i}$ would be to choose
>   the label that has the highest probability in $\mathbf{a}_{i}$, i.e.
>   $y_{i}=\text{argmax}_{k}{\mathbf{a}_{i}[k]}$. However, this greedy approach
>   fails to take into account the dependencies between subsequent labels.
>   For example, it may be more likely to have a token with the PHI type
>   STATE followed by a token with the PHI type ZIP than any other PHI
>   type. Even though the label prediction layer has the capacity to
>   capture such dependencies to a certain degree, it may be preferable to
>   allow the model to directly learn these dependencies in the last layer
>   of the model.
>
> One way to model such dependencies is to incorporate a matrix $T$ that
>   contains the transition probabilities between two subsequent labels.
>   $T[i,j]$ is the probability that a token with label $i$ is followed by
>   a token with the label $j$. The score of a label sequence $y_{1:n}$ is
>   defined as the sum of the probabilities of individual labels and the
>   transition probabilities: $$ s(y_{1:n}) = { \sum_{i=1}^{n}
> > \mathbf{a}_{i}[y_{i}]+  \sum_{i=2}^{n} T [y_{i-1},y_{i}} ]. $$ These
>   scores can be turned into probabilities of the label sequences by
>   taking a softmax function over all possible label sequences.  During
>   the training phase, the objective is to maximize the log probability
>   of the gold label sequence. In the testing phase, given an input
>   sequence of tokens, the corresponding sequence of predicted labels is
>   chosen as the one that maximizes the score.

The network:

[image]

Code: https://github.com/Franck-Dernoncourt/NeuroNER